# google search tab shortcut not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I often use the "tab" key to quickly browse google search results but recently it stopped working.

usually pressing tab after searching puts a tiny arrow next to the results. this way you can easily use your keyboard arrows to navigate to the one you want.

Comment: let everyone else know this is a good answer and accept it!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This thing was making me crazy lately. Cleaning up cookies as some suggest was not an option as I'm always logged in into my Gmail account. Indeed, I could have switched to Incognito mode to have keyboard shortcuts at my fingertips but for God's sake who would be content with such UX?

So I spent half an hour and finally found that Lou Kosak said [in the Google product forums:](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/2Xm9L8kEfUE)

> Just found a (the?) fix. Turns out <kbd>tab</kbd> + <kbd>arrow keys</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> navigation of search results only works if Google Instant is turned on (see https://superuser.com/a/554324).

To summarize the superuser answer:

- go to google.com when logged in
- click Settings in the bottom right
- click "Search Settings"
- update your "Google Instant Predictions" setting to "Only when my computer is fast enough" or "Always show instant results".

**Update 2017-07-31**: Google has dropped Instant search. See: http://searchengineland.com/google-dropped-google-instant-search-279674. This means that this solution does not work anymore.

Comment: Thanks!, this was exactly what i needed

Comment: Perfect! might just add you need to reload chrome for the setting to be applied.

Comment: but I don't want instant search results or whatever, I want only my tab button working :-(
And even with "Always show instant results" it's not working.

Comment: I didn't notice how often I used this feature until it stopped working.

Comment: 2017: It's not working again even updated settings

Comment: I don't see the settings anymore and the shortcut stop working

Comment: @ipeluffo they've removed the instant search features - http://searchengineland.com/google-dropped-google-instant-search-279674, and therefore, this feature.

Comment: I've added a plugin that is almost working here: https://github.com/scripter-co/google-chrome-search-tabbing - i'll get it on the app store in the next day or two once i fix a couple of issues.

Comment: I've added the extension that does what we want here: https://github.com/scripter-co/google-chrome-search-tabbing / https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-chrome-search-tabb/fgmnkcffojicmpaohafpiceihcpeleka

Comment: I also created an open source extension to fix this and add enhancements: https://github.com/infokiller/google-search-navigator

You can install it from the Chrome Webstore: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-search-navigator/cohamjploocgoejdfanacfgkhjkhdkek

Hope you find it useful, but in any case- feedback is welcome!

Answer (score 3):

I run into this periodically and clearing browsing data (`Settings -> More Tools -> Clear browsing data`) seems to fix it for me. It seems like I have to clear cookies in order to get it working again.

Comment: Clearing cache solves only for 1 session. After that it won't work for me till next clearing.

Answer (score 3):

> **Update:**
>   since google dropped instant search, this won't work out of the box, but [this chrome extention](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-search-keyboard-sh/iobmefdldoplhmonnnkchglfdeepnfhd/related?hl=en) fixes it rather easily.
>
> [here](https://superuser.com/questions/509192/tab-enter-no-longer-taking-me-to-first-google-search-result-in-chrome/)'s a more hacky way to do it (older solution).

---

Since the problem persisted even on other computers (on the same google profile) i found a permanent solution:

google search settings (from any google search page top right - the gear icon) -> google instant predictions -> enable (only when my computer is fast enough).

apparently the two features are linked. i had found an article on it somewhere else, but couldn't find it to quote it here. if someone does, please append in comment.